# A specific parameter is not included in HTTP request on Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I have a strange issue in Angular and Ionic 2. I have the following provider:

```
  getTransportations = function (category, maxResults) {    
    let url = `${this.domain}/wp-json/gf/v2/forms/1/entries?_labels=1&paging[page_size]=${maxResults}`;
    if (category !== 'all') {
      let search = {
        field_filters: [{
          key: '2',
          operator: 'is',
          value: category
        }]
      };
      let url = `${this.domain}/wp-json/gf/v2/forms/1/entries?_labels=1&paging[page_size]=${maxResults}&search=${encodeURI(JSON.stringify(search))}`;
      console.log(url);

    }
    let headers: Headers = new Headers();
    headers.append("Authorization", "Basic " + this.bt);
    headers.append("Content-type", "application/json");
    return this.http.get(url, {
        headers: headers
      })
      .map(response => response.json())

  };
```

If category is `all` then the provider works as expected. However, if the category is something else, on the Dev tools on Chrome, in the tab of Network, I can see the called url without the search parameter. Just `_labels` and `paging`. But, the `console.log` I added inside the if works and it prints the right url that if I use it on Postman, I get the filtered results I want.

I tried different ways to concat strings, but I have the same problem all the time.

Comment: "without the search parameter". What do you see exactly?

Comment: Query string parameters: `_labels=1&paging[page_size]=15`

Comment: This is impossible, at least `&search=` would have to be printed out because it does not depend on any variables in your template literal string.

Comment: It doesn't. That's why I find it strange. And the url if I copy paste on network tab is this one:

`http://...../wp-json/gf/v2/forms/1/entries?_labels=1&paging[page_size]=15`

Removed the domain name

Comment: The problem involves too much moving parts. It could be easily debugged with two `console.log(url)` - inside and outside `if` block. If you have a suspicion that something goes wrong, it's always a good idea to narrow down the problem and debug variables instead of trying to figure it out in indirect way (HTTP request).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is scope problem. `let` is block scoped.

```
let url = `${this.domain}/wp-json/gf/v2/forms/1/entries?_labels=1&paging[page_size]=${maxResults}&search=${encodeURI(JSON.stringify(search))}`;
```

has a scope that belongs to `if (...) { ... }`. These two `url` are different variables, and the one that is being assigned inside `if` is never used (except `console.log`).

It should be

```
url = `${this.domain}/wp-json/gf/v2/forms/1/entries?_labels=1&paging[page_size]=${maxResults}&search=${encodeURI(JSON.stringify(search))}`;
```

Comment: I cannot believe that I forgot to delete the `let` when I copied paste the url line of code. Thanks so much.

Comment: @Tasos You're welcome. I usually use if..else consistently with let, `let url; if (...) url = ... else url = ...`. It's a bit more verbose but treats both conditions as equal and prevents a situation like that. I probably started to do that after similar accident.

Comment: Good point. Thanks for the suggestion. I will probably follow it from now on